# Separate Work Sheets based on year using axlsx gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, axlsx

I have used `axlsx gem` for downloading data into excel. I have added worksheets with each sheet having 100 rows. In my data i have year column based on year i need to add sheets.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You would just sort your data by year (at least) and add a worksheet for each year:

```
data_by_year.each do |thing|
  wb.add_worksheet(:name => thing.year.to_s) do |sheet|
    sheet.add_row ["First Column", "Second", "Third"]
    sheet.add_row [thing.first, thing.second, thing.third]
  end
end
```

There is a `workbook.worksheets` instance attribute of the type `SimpleTypedList`, but this is not considered public API. With that you may have success adding to worksheets whether or not your data is in year order.